# QBluetoothSocket::connectToService Hanging on ServiceLookupState - Why?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, bluetooth

I have an application which connects (or should connect) as a client to a Bluetooth service on an Android device using the [Qt Bluetooth API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html). The code for doing so is not complicated and does not differ much from the sample given in the [Qt Bluetooth Overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html), though it is distributed a bit as it's part of a class.

In the constructor:

```
mBluetoothSocket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
```

In a "waitForServiceConnection" method:

```
    mBluetoothSocket->connectToService(address, uuid);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < timeout; ++i)
    {
         QTime delayLimit = QTime::currentTime().addSecs(1);
         while( QTime::currentTime() < delayLimit ) QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
            qDebug() << "Current socket state is " << mBluetoothSocket->state() << endl;
            if (mServiceConnected)
            {
                    return;
            }
         }
     ...
     }
```

For each iteration of the for loop (for timeouts of up to 60 seconds) I get the following output:

> Current socket state is  QBluetoothSocket::ServiceLookupState

There is a socketStateChanged slot which takes the stateChanged signal from the socket and contains this:

```
qDebug() << "Socket state changed to " << socketState << endl;
```

which outputs:

> Socket state changed to  QBluetoothSocket::ServiceLookupState

only once. If I manually check the socket state in the loop it is always ServiceLookupState as well.

I'm unfortunately not 100% certain what *exactly* ServiceLookupState entails. [Qt's documentation on the QBluetoothSocket class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothsocket.html) reports

> Socket is querying connection parameters.

which I suspect means looking up ports or something.

The desktop client successfully finds the service registered on the device with QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent. I have tested this against a known-good Bluetooth service (the Android BluetoothChat sample) with the same results so I'm fairly certain the issue is with the desktop client. What am I doing wrong?

No exceptions are thrown and QBluetoothSocket::error() always indicates no error.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the code itself - the issue was a consequence of it being in a library that was being called from some unit tests. It works fine when called from a standard Qt console app.

As the unit tests can't really address the Bluetooth components properly anyway this is acceptable.